# Doubly Linked List in Python

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, linked-list

I implemented a doubly linked list in Python. Please tell me what I can do to improve performance, what methods I should add, etc. I gave it the best Big O time perfomance/complexity I could. So, here it is:

```
class DoublyLinkedList():
    """
    A basic class implementing a doubly linked list.

    DoublyLinkedList() - new empty linked list
    DoublyLinkedList(iterable) - new linked list with the items of the iterable:
    head - iterable[0] tail - iterable[-1]
    """

    class _Node():
        """A doubly linked list node class."""

        def __init__(self, value):
            """Initialize default values."""
            self._value = value
            self._next = None
            self._prev = None

    def __init__(self, seq=()):
        """Initialize default values."""
        self._head = None
        self._tail = None
        self._size = 0  # set default values

        self.extend(seq)  # copy iterables values

    def __iter__(self):
        """Implement iter(self)."""
        node = self._head
        while node:
            yield node._value
            node = node._next

    def __len__(self):
        """Implement len(self). Return the number of items in list."""
        return self._size

    def __str__(self):
        """Define string casting for the list."""
        return 'None <= ' + ' <=> '.join(map(str, self)) + ' => None'

    def __repr__(self):
        """Return repr(self)."""
        return self.__str__()

    def __contains__(self, item):
        """Implement 'in' access: if item in."""
        for i in self:
            if i == item:
                return True
        return False

    def __eq__(self, other):
        """Implement comparison: a == b."""
        if type(other) is not type(self):  # check if other is dll
            return False
        if len(self) != len(other):
            return False
        for i, j in zip(self, other):
            if i != j:
                return False
        return True

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        """Implement indexing access: a[b]."""
        # change index if negative
        index = self._size + index if index < 0 else index
        if 0 <= index < self._size:
            for i, item in enumerate(self):
                if i == index:
                    return item
        else:
            raise IndexError('list index out of range')

    def __setitem__(self, index, item):
        """Implement indexed assignment."""
        # change index if negative
        index = self._size + index if index < 0 else index
        if 0 <= index < self._size:
            i = 0
            node = self._head
            while i < index:
                node = node._next
                i += 1
            node._value = item
        else:
            raise IndexError('list assignment index out of range')

    def __delitem__(self, index):
        """Implement indexed deletion."""
        # change index if negative
        if type(index) is not int:
            raise TypeError('list index must be an integer')

        index = self._size + index if index < 0 else index
        if 0 < index < self._size - 1:
            i = 0
            node = self._head
            while i < index:
                node = node._next
                i += 1
            node._prev._next = node._next
            node._next._prev = node._prev
            self._size -= 1
        elif index == 0 and self._head is not None:  # case for head
            self._head = self._head._next
            self._head._prev = None
            self._size -= 1
        elif index == self._size - 1 and self._head is not None:
            self._tail = self._tail._prev
            self._tail._next = None
            self._size -= 1
        else:
            raise IndexError('list index out of range')

    def insertStart(self, item):
        """Insert an item to the _head of the list."""
        new_node = self._Node(item)
        if not self._head:  # or if not self._tail
            self._head = new_node
            self._tail = new_node
        else:
            new_node._next = self._head
            self._head._prev = new_node
            self._head = new_node
        self._size += 1

    def insertEnd(self, item):
        """Insert an item at the _tail of the list."""
        new_node = self._Node(item)
        if not self._tail:  # or if not self._head
            self._tail = new_node
            self._head = new_node
        else:
            new_node._prev = self._tail
            self._tail._next = new_node
            self._tail = new_node
        self._size += 1

    def insert(self, index, item):
        """Insert an item before the specified index."""
        t = type(index)
        if t is not int:
            raise TypeError('{} cannot be interpreted as an integer'.format(t))
        else:
            # change index if negative
            index = self._size + index if index < 0 else index
            if index > self._size - 1:  # check for special cases
                self.insertEnd(item)
            elif index <= 0:
                self.insertStart(item)
            else:  # iterate through and insert item
                i = 0
                node = self._head
                while i < index - 1:
                    node = node._next
                    i += 1
                new_node = self._Node(item)
                new_node._next = node._next
                new_node._prev = node
                node._next = new_node
                new_node._next._prev = new_node
                self._size += 1

    def extend(self, seq=()):
        """Extend list by appending elements from the iterable."""
        for i in seq:
            self.insertEnd(i)

    def remove(self, item):
        """
        Remove the first occurence of the value(default _tail).

        Raises a ValueError if the is not present.
        Raises an IndexError if the list is empty.
        """
        if not self._head:
            raise IndexError("remove from an empty list")
        else:
            if self._head._value == item:  # case for head
                self._head = self._head._next
                self._head._prev = None
            elif self._tail._value == item:  # case for tail
                self._tail = self._tail._prev
                self._tail._next = None
            else:
                node = self._head
                try:
                    while node._value != item:
                        node = node._next
                    node._prev._next = node._next
                    node._next._prev = node._prev
                except AttributeError:  # mute the original error
                    raise ValueError('value not present in list') from None
            self._size -= 1

    def pop(self, index=-1):
        """
        Remove and return item at specified index (default last).

        Raises IndexError if list is empty or index is out of range.
        """
        if self._size == 0:  # check if list is empty
            raise IndexError("pop from an empty list")
        t = type(index)
        if t is not int:  # check if index is integer
            raise TypeError('{} cannot be interpreted as an integer'.format(t))
        item = self[index]  # save the item to return
        del self[index]
        return item

    def index(self, item):
        """Return index of first occurence of specified item. -1 if absent."""
        for index, el in enumerate(self):
            if el == item:
                return index
        return -1

    def count(self, item):
        """Return number of occurrences of item."""
        count = 0
        for i in self:
            if i == item:
                count += 1
        return count

    def clear(self):
        """Remove all the items from the list."""
        self._head = None
        self._tail = None
        self._size = 0

    def reverse(self):
        """Reverse list in place."""
        tmp = None
        curr = self._head

        while curr:
            tmp = curr._prev
            curr._prev = curr._next
            curr._next = tmp
            curr = curr._prev

        if tmp:
            self._head = tmp._prev

    def sort(self):
        """Sort list in place."""
        self._head = self._merge_sort(self._head)

    def _merge(self, left, right):  # merge two lists
        t_head = self._Node(None)
        curr = t_head

        while left and right:
            if left._value < right._value:
                curr._next = left
                left = left._next
            else:
                curr._next = right
                right = right._next
            curr = curr._next

        if left is None:
            curr._next = right
        if right is None:
            curr._next = left

        return t_head._next

    def _split(self, lst):  # split a list
        if lst is None or lst._next is None:
            left = lst
            right = None
            return left, right
        else:
            mid = lst
            fast = lst._next

            while fast is not None:
                fast = fast._next

                if fast is not None:
                    fast = fast._next
                    mid = mid._next
        left = lst
        right = mid._next
        mid._next = None

        return left, right

    def _merge_sort(self, t_head):  # merge sort
        if t_head is None:
            return t_head
        if t_head._next is None:
            return t_head

        left, right = self._split(t_head)
        left = self._merge_sort(left)
        right = self._merge_sort(right)

        return self._merge(left, right)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dll = DoublyLinkedList([2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 3])
    print(dll)
    dll.insertEnd(4)
    dll.insertStart(0)
    dll.sort()
    dll.insert(-11, 'start')
    print(dll)
    print(dll.pop())
    print(dll.pop(2))
    dll.remove(4)
    dll.extend('someiterable')
    dll.index(8)
    print(dll.count(4))
    print(dll)
```

Answer (score 6):

1. `__getitem__`, `__setitem__`, and `__delitem__` should share index-validation and repair code. In `__delitem__` you check the type of `index` as well as its algebraic sign (whether it's negative). In `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`, you check only the algebraic sign; did you intend to not check the type of `index` in those two functions? If so, you should comment on why. If not, then you should write something like

   ```
   def __validate_and_repair_index(self, index):
       if type(index) is not int:
           raise TypeError('list index must be an integer')
       # count from the end if "index" is negative
       index = self._size + index if index < 0 else index
       return index
   ```

   and call it from all three of `__getitem__`, `__setitem__`, and `__delitem__`, and maybe some other places, too.
2. The following block in `__delitem__` seems to have a bug (testing `_head` instead of `_tail`)

   ```
   elif index == self._size - 1 and self._head is not None:
       self._tail = self._tail._prev
       self._tail._next = None
       self._size -= 1
   ```
3. Many of your docstrings and comments are vapid and should be removed or made informative. For example `"""Initialize default values"""` in `__init__` doesn't tell the reader anything, but wastes the reader's time. A docstring in `__len(self)__` that says `"""Implement len(self)"""` similarly adds no information and simply wastes your reader's attention and energy. A comment that says `change index if negative` right above code that does nothing other than change index if negative is not an informative comment. A better one would be `count from the end if index is negative` because that's the *intent* of `change index if negative`: that's *why* you're changing index if negative. A comment like `if t is not int:  # check if index is integer` is unnecessary: it simply re-iterates the plain meaning of the code in other words. If you were writing a story, you would not write "I went to the store this morning; this morning, to the store I went." So why would you write comments like that in code that is already crystal clear and can't have any intent other than the obvious one? There are more cases in the code. Some comments can profitably made into `asserts`. For instance, in `insertStart`, you might replace `# or not self._tail` with `assert not self._tail` on a new line.
4. The fields of `_Node` should not be named `_value`, `_prev`, and `_next` because the underscore prefix conventionally connotes "protected," meaning accessible only in subclasses. Various linters and IDEs (like PyCharm) will flag every access of those fields because `_Node` is used directly in the rest of the code, not through subclasses.
5. Is there a bug in `__contains__`? Should `i == item` be `i.value == item`?. Likewise, should `__getitem__` return the `Node` object or the value of the `Node` object?
6. I'm allowed to insert `math.nan` and `cmath.nanj`, but they will fail equality tests such as that in `__contains__`. Fixing this requires some design. Should nans be disallowed? How? Silently rejected? Ignored? Raise a `ValueError`? With or without a message?

As a general comment, if you write tests along with your code before going to code review, you will have many fewer issues in the review. I highly recommend [hypothesis for Python](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which runs on [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/getting-started.html). Here, for instance, is a `strategy` for `hypothesis` that generated many examples that broke much of the original code:

```
from typing import Union
import hypothesis.strategies as st

Atom = Union[str, float, bool, int, complex]

PayloadStrategy = st.deferred(
    lambda: st.from_type(Atom) |
            st.lists(PayloadStrategy) |
            st.tuples(PayloadStrategy) |
            st.iterables(PayloadStrategy) |
            # st.sets(PayloadStrategy) |  # TODO: why doesn't this work?
            st.dictionaries(
                keys=st.from_type(str),
                values=PayloadStrategy))
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of passing an iterable to the constructor, you could use `*values` as the argument:

```
    def __init__(self, *values):
        # ... 
        self.extend(values)
```

This will allow you to use:

```
dll = DoublyLinkedList(2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 3)
```

instead of

```
dll = DoublyLinkedList([2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 3])
```

---

You are relying on `__iter__(self)` (which creates a generator) for the implementation of `__contains__`, `__eq__`, `__getitem__`, `index`, and `count`.  It would be more efficient to simply loop through your linked list manually, rather than creating a generator, and context switching back and forth between the method code and the generator code.

---

**BUG**: `remove(self, item)` will fail if you remove the only item from list of 1 item.

```
    # ...
        self._head = self._head._next   # self._head = None
        self._head._prev = None         # None has no attribute ._prev
    # ...
```

---

**BUG**: Neither `reverse(self):` nor `sort(self):` changes `self._tail`!

---

`__getitem__(self, index):`, `__setitem__(self, index, item):` and `insert(self, index, item):` do not take advantage of the double-linking.  If `index` is in the last half of the list, iterating from `self._tail` should be faster.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your review :) I will definitely change those bugs and make indexing faster while taking advantage of double linking. Now for the constructor argument, I think that passing an iterable is more efficient, for example passing multiple values as an iterable is very easy, just pass them as a list or tuple, but if one has an iterable then it would have them do a for loop, and why, when we can do that for them? As for relying on iterator, I think it's actually good to do so, because why manually iterate through items when you have an iterator. But hey, thanks for those bugs :)

Comment: Do you also have a bug in `__delitem__` in the third branch where you are deleting the tail, but the code says `and self._head is not None`?

Comment: As with `remove`, `__delitem__` fails when the list has one item.